# How to do the query SQL to get a result like this

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
game
-----
id
start_time
player_p_id

player
-------
p_id
username

answer
------
id
correct
text

game_answer
-----------
game_id
answers_id
```

Hello everyone, How could I create a SQL query to select (game.id, player.name, [score]) ?

I am expecting to get a result game's id, player's name, and score.
Score is the sum of correct answer.

I tried this query but it doesn't work

```
SELECT g.id, p.username, g.start_time, sum(a.correct)
from GAME g
INNER JOIN PLAYER p ON g.player_p_id = p.p_id
INNER JOIN GAME_ANSWER ga ON ga.GAME_ID = g.ID
INNER JOIN ANSWER a ON a.id = ga.ANSWERS_ID
ORDER BY g.id;
```

Note: answer.correct is either o or 1

Comment: Please provide some details about the input data and what result you expect to see.

Comment: @shrek it is there. I expect to see id of game, player's name, and score. Score is the sum of all corect answer

Comment: What have you tried?  Lookup using `join` and `sum` and `group by`...

Comment: @sgeddes i tried this but it's error 
SELECT distinct g.id, p.username, g.start_time, sum(a.correct)
from GAME g
INNER JOIN PLAYER p ON g.player_p_id = p.p_id
INNER JOIN GAME_ANSWER ga ON ga.GAME_ID = g.ID
INNER JOIN ANSWER a ON a.id = ga.ANSWERS_ID
ORDER BY g.id;

Comment: Providing the actual error message may help.

Comment: First obvious problem is that your query refers to a column `a.correct`, which doesn't exist in the table definitions provided.  Presumably you mean `a.isCorrect`.

Comment: You say that `answer.isCorrect` is boolean.  There is no boolean type in SQL.  Your tag implies you are using Oracle; there is certainly no such thing as a column of boolean type in Oracle.  What is the actual type of the column?

Comment: Additional to the afore mentioned problems in your query/question, your query uses `game.player_p_id` and `player.p_id`, yet these columns aren't in your schema description. But I guess, apart from these issues, you mainly want to `GROUP BY g.id, g.start_time, p.id, p.username`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two obvious syntax problems with your query.

It references various columns by different names than what you give in the table definitions.  For instance, the query references `a.correct`, but you show that the column in `answers` is called '`isCorrect`.  You are probably getting error messages indicating the columns don't exist.  Use the correct names for all the columns.

(Seems like you have now updated the table definitions so that the column names match.  So the above may not be an issue.)

You have no GROUP BY clause in the query.  SUM is a group function.  If you have both ungrouped values (`g.id, p.username, g.start_time`) and grouped values in your select list, you need a GROUP BY clause.  Usually you simply include every column from the select list that's not surrounded by a group function.  In this case it looks like you want `GROUP BY g.id, p.username, g.start_time`.  This should precede the ORDER BY clause.

You have now clarified that `isCorrect` contains 0 or 1, so with the other corrections, the SUM function should give the result you want.

Comment: WOW! i changed the structure a little bit in order to make it easier. But after I put order by, it works. You saved my life :D have a good day!